# How to change appearance of nix-env packages installed on non nixOS?

Tags: nix

I installed vscode using nix-env command, `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.vscode`. My system is dark. But, VS Code using light file portal and weird default cursor theme for Xorg. While it's not a big deal, but, I want my system consistent. So how do I tell VS Code to use dark theme and change the cursor theme?

Answer (score 0):

So usually, nix applications should follow the style of the operating system, but `vscode` is built using [electron](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/cbapzu/use_gtk_theme/), and is therefore not really relying on GTK/Qt theming (except for the File bar I think, but in my case it is dark as expected). However, when I run it the first time, I get a message asking me the theme I'd like to use (tested on KDE Plasma):

[image]

If I click on "light", I get:

[image]

So my guess is that you should instead change the color theme via preferences (bottom left gear) > dark, to get back to :

[image]

If it is not working for your, can you maybe post a screenshot and more information about your system?